# In REST API for neo4j, how to merge or create nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I am running a local instance of neo4j ("Community" edition) on a Windows 10 laptop.  My client is in Java and uses the REST API (via port 7474) to talk with the neo4j database.

QUESTION:  is there some way to get the equivalent of a `MERGE/CREATE` directive in cypher to happen via the REST API call to `/db/data/node` endpoint?

I'm guessing that I could impose a unique constraint on different node types and achieve the desired behavior.  But out of the box, what I am hoping for is a single endpoint -- Eg, `/db/data/node` -- which either creates or merges the inbound data with any existing nodes in the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to figure out how to get the "equivalent" of Cypher clauses like `MERGE/CREATE`. You can use Cypher directly via either of these REST endpoints:

- [/db/data/transaction](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/rest-api-transactional.html)
- [/db/data/cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/rest-api-cypher.html)

[EDITED]

However, if you only want to use the `/db/data/node` endpoint, you can take advantage of [unique indexing](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/rest-api-unique-indexes.html) and use either the `uniqueness=get_or_create` or `uniqueness=create_or_fail` URL parameters.

Comment: Yes, I know.  The question is whether using the published REST API endpoint `/db/data/node` supplies behavior analogous to MERGE/CREATE.  I think the answer is no, and that the REST API consumer has to manage this kind of duplicate/collision.

Comment: I'm giving you credit for helpful responses.  But I think the heart of the matter is that endpoint `/db/data/node` is faulty with respect to type duplication/collisions.  I think it would work better if labels could be attached to the node at creation-time.  Then if the neo4j server detected a type duplicate, it would simply merge in any additional labels in the HTTP request.