# In neo4j 2.x REST API, how to create/get unique nodes using constraints?

Tags: neo4j

This article is a follow-up to the question I [posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899411/in-rest-api-for-neo4j-how-to-merge-or-create-nodes). The issue is that in neo4j 2.x docs, there is a [note](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/rest-api-unique-indexes.html) to the effect that constraints are recommended for creating or getting unique nodes:

> As of Neo4j 2.0, unique constraints have been added. These make Neo4j
>   enforce the uniqueness, guaranteeing that uniqueness is maintained.
>   See the section called “Constraints” for details about this. For most
>   cases, the unique constraints should be used rather than the features
>   described below.

But in the `Constraints` sections of the neo4j docs, there is no explanation of how to invoke the REST API to create-or-get a unique node (unique on some label/property combination).

QUESTION:  in neo4j 2.0, should I use `uniqueness=get_or_create`?  If not, then what REST API endpoints are recommended for doing this?

Comment: I may have answered my own question.  When you create a unique-constraint on a node-property, then neo4j automatically created a corresponding index for that node-property.  At this point, I think you just use the REST API endpoints for get-or-create (ie, employing the `uniqueness=get_or_create` parameter in the queries).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the unique constraints and schema indexes are created and maintained with Cypher.

```
(CREATE/DROP) INDEX ON :Label(property)
```

The application of the index/constraints happens automatically under the hood when running cypher queries.

`MERGE` is the get-or-create equivalent.

If you create or update a node with a duplicate property, that update will not happen and you receive an error.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not going to check off your answer, though, because the focus of the question is on what REST API endpoints facilitate create-or-get for nodes.